# Identify which EntityManager Entity was loaded

Tags: java, database, entity-framework, hibernate, jpa

Needed to gather information from 3 different databases from a @Entity in an ArrayList(), but now after ArrayList() being loaded'm having trouble identifying which of Session / EntityManager it belongs.

I can not identify just by ID, because I'm going to have objects with the same id, one for each database.

Is there any way to create an attribute with database/EntityManager reference inside the @Entity class? Hibernate own and store this information to make a Select Query?

Comment: What about using the EntityManager.contains(entity) method?

Comment: I tried to but all EntityManager returned false, is that my objects are missing the persistent state? after you select the objects and put together in a list, I'll send for a jsf table and display to the User, and then when the User clicks on a table row, an event is triggered, and then make the check EntityManager.contains (entity) that is to receive the authority by the listener connection with the entityManager is lost?

Comment: Your entities are deteached that is the reason the method returns false

Comment: ok, I have to found out why my objects are becoming datached.

Comment: I found this on the internet: "Traditionally, this problem was addressed with" data access objects ", objects Whose sole purpose is to transport data between layers Implementing and Maintaining these objects is tedious When an entity object is returned from a stateless session bean to JSF managed bean, it passe detached " and now?

Comment: Yes, that's the reason, you can use a Statefull Session Bean with an PersistenceContext Extended to avoid this, but I don't think it's the best solution, Can you explain your requirement Why you have 3 entity managers ??

Comment: It is that these databases are not of my application, are managed by another application, I only have permission to read them, I am creating an application that shows the User data of the three applications / database in a view only .

Comment: I'll give it a studied then: Statefull Session Bean with an Extended PersistenceContext, thanks.

Comment: I set my application with ApplicationScoped and  Stateful it worked :D thx.